# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: jsp Unterminated &lt;c:if tag

Tags: jsp

I want to remove current status from jsp file when a person tries to change his/her status. My code was working fine. 
I have added **c:if** and then I have started getting this error.
Please correct me where am i going wrong.

```
  </c:when><c:otherwise>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><bean:message key="changeStatus.new"/></td>
                        <td>
                            <html:select property="memberStatus">
                                <html:option value=""><bean:message key="global.select.empty" /></html:option>
                                <c:forEach var="status" items="${memberStatuses}">
                                    <html:option value="${status}"><bean:message key="changeStatus.${status}"/></html:option>
                                    <c:if test="${status == member.status}" <html:option value="${status}"><bean:message key="changeStatus.${status}"/></html:option>
                                    </c:if>
                                </c:forEach>    
                            </html:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

   </c:otherwise></c:choose>
```

Comment: try adding `>` close tag `<c:if test="${status == member.status}"` just here.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Gurkan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jsp Unterminated `&lt;c:if` tag

The problem occurs when you overlooked to add a close tag. So you need close tag `&gt;`(i.e. > sign) for `c:if` too.

```
<c:if test="${status == member.status}" > <html:option ...>
                                        ^
                                       Here
```